# Iterate through nested List to return inner List by specified param

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

The goal is to return the inner list of Object with a given param from the data list. The layer on which this Object will be found may vary.

The pseudo code for the Object is

```
class Object {
   var id: Int
   var innerObjects: ArrayList<Object>
}
```

If `innerObjects` param is null then we reached the leaf.

We are given `ArrayList<Object>` which is the data and `id` we are searching for. The Object we search can be on any level of the list.

What I have now is this piece of code but it only checks for 2 levels of the list. Please, suggest a solution that would work for any number of levels in the list. Possibly with recursion.

```
private fun getObject(data: ArrayList<Object>, id: Int): ArrayList<Object> {
        var result = ArrayList<Object>()
        for (i in 0 until data.size) {
            if (data[i].id == id) {
                result = data[i].innerObjects
            } else {
                for (j in 0 until data[i].innerObjects.size) {
                    if (data[i].innerObjects[j].id == id) {
                        result = data[i].innerObjects[j].innerObjects
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

By the way, the code is in Kotlin but feel free to suggest solution **in Kotlin or Java.**

Comment: You need to use a graph traversal algorithm, such as [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: @ruakh looked into those but the problem I faced that my return breaks the recursion. In the examples I found the algorithms don't return specific Node. Could you provide an example with the return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written java code for the solution :

```
ArrayList<TreeNode> solve(TreeNode treeNode, int id) {
    if(treeNode == null) return null;
    if(treeNode.id == id) return treeNode.nodes;
    if(treeNode.nodes == null) return null;
    ArrayList<TreeNode> ans = null, temp = null;
    for(TreeNode t: treeNode.nodes) {
        temp = solve(t, id);
        if(temp != null) ans = temp;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Demo on Ideone : https://ideone.com/cMmAqD

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, it helped me to figure out how to apply it for my case, I will accept your answer and post my code also for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

So, in this case using basic recursion will solve this, but beware, because this kind of searching can quickly produce literal `StackOverflowException`s.

```
fun getInnerObjectsById(nodes: ArrayList<Object>, id: Int) : ArrayList<Object>? {
    nodes.forEach{
        val ans = solve(it, id)
        if (ans != null) return ans
    }
    return null
}

fun getInnerObjectsById(obj: Object?, id: Int): ArrayList<Object>? {
    if (obj?.id == null || obj.innerObjects == null) return null
    if (obj.id == id) return obj.innerObjects
    return obj.innerObjects?.mapNotNull {
        solve(it, id)
    }?.firstOrNull()
}
```

This is a more involved, but imperative search.

```
fun getInnerObjectsById(data: ArrayList<Object>, id: Int): ArrayList<Object>? {
    var activeList: List<Object> = data
    while (true) {
        val match = activeList.firstOrNull { it.id == id }
        if (match != null) return match.innerObjects
        activeList = activeList.flatMap { it.innerObjects ?: emptyList<Object>() }

        if (!activeList.isNotEmpty())
            return null
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, tried the first one but it doesn't find the Object by id. it only returns innerObjects of  the last item in data no matter the id, and the second one doesn't compile as data is ArrayList and it doesn't have param id  on line 4

Comment: Finally had a chance to address this with a compiler in front of me, and have corrected my solutions. I would highly suggest not using the recursive search. And also, you're final solution and the recursive solution in general, are using nested loops, which are also less desirable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I applied for my case in Kotlin for those who are interested!

```
private fun getObjectById(item: Object, id: Int): ArrayList<Object>? {
    if (item.id == id) return item.innerObjects
    for (child in item.innerObjects) {
        val temp = getObjectById(child, id)
        if (temp!!.isNotEmpty()) return temp
    }
    return ArrayList()
}

fun combineLists(data: ArrayList<Object>?, id: Int) {
    for (j in 0 until data.size) {
         getObjectById(data[j], id)?.let {
            result.clear()
            result.addAll(it)
         }
    }
}
```